# How to create a JSON Key Set from two JSON string

Tags: java, json, string, jwk

I have two json string coresponding to "**sig**" and "**enc**".

`String a={ "kty": "someText", "e": "someText", "use": "sig", "kid": "someText", "alg": "someText", "n": "someText"}`

`String b= { "kty": "someText", "e": "someText", "use": "enc", "kid": "someText", "alg": "someText", "n": "someText" }`

I need to combine them both like this:

`{ "keys": [ { "kty": "someText", "e": "someText", "use": "sig", "kid": "someText", "alg": "someText", "n": "someText" }, { "kty": "someText", "e": "someText", "use": "enc", "kid": "someText", "alg": "someText", "n": "someText" } ] }`

The resulting JSON is nothing but JWKS which includes both **sig** and **enc** public keys. I have replaced the actual values for these parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code :

```
public void test(){
        String a="{ \"kty\": \"someText\", \"e\": \"someText\", \"use\": \"sig\", \"kid\": \"someText\", \"alg\": \"someText\", \"n\": \"someText\"}";
        String b= "{ \"kty\": \"someText\", \"e\": \"someText\", \"use\": \"enc\", \"kid\": \"someText\", \"alg\": \"someText\", \"n\": \"someText\" }";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(a);
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(b);
        JSONArray objects1 = new JSONArray();
        objects1.put(jsonObject);
        objects1.put(jsonObject1);

        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject2.put("keys",objects1);
        System.out.println(jsonObject2);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
{"keys":[{"kty":"someText","e":"someText","use":"sig","kid":"someText","alg":"someText","n":"someText"},{"kty":"someText","e":"someText","use":"enc","kid":"someText","alg":"someText","n":"someText"}]}
```

Library used : [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20211205)

Comment: I have tried the same, but my jsonObject will have escape characters in the output. Any ide on how to resolve it?

Comment: @yuhubug Are you sure those escape characters ware not present before *merging* those two JSON objects? If they ware not could you provide example of *correct* JSONs, what you expected and what you got instead?

Comment: @yuhubug you will be having an escape characters in the input JSON (a & b)?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following logic implemented with `org.json` library.

```
public void generateJSONObject() {
    String a = "{ \"kty\": \"someText\", \"e\": \"someText\", \"use\": \"sig\", \"kid\": \"someText\", \"alg\": \"someText\", \"n\": \"someText\"}";
    String b = "{ \"kty\": \"someText\", \"e\": \"someText\", \"use\": \"enc\", \"kid\": \"someText\", \"alg\": \"someText\", \"n\": \"someText\" }";
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(a);
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(b);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.append("keys", jsonObject1);
    jsonObject.append("keys", jsonObject2);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
  }
```

Comment: why the `parser.parse(a).toString()`?

Comment: Construct a JSONObject from a source JSON text string. This is the most commonly used JSONObject constructor as defined in org.json.JSONObject,

public JSONObject(String source) throws JSONException {
        this(new JSONTokener(source));
}

Comment: @BipinKumarChaurasia yes: just pass `a` or `b` to the constructor.

Comment: @BipinKumarChaurasia I have tried the same, but my jsonObject will have escape characters in the output. Any ide on how to resolve it?

Comment: No, you won't be having the escape quotes as the following output had been printed after executing above function,
`{"keys":[{"kty":"someText","e":"someText","use":"sig","kid":"someText","alg":"someText","n":"someText"},{"kty":"someText","e":"someText","use":"enc","kid":"someText","alg":"someText","n":"someText"}]}
`